# xpath not getting selected

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have just started using Scrapy:
Here is an example of a website that I want to crawl :

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shame

The code for my Spider :

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from dic_crawler.items import DicCrawlerItem

from urlBuilder import *   

class Dic_crawler(BaseSpider):
    name = "dic"
    allowed_domains = ["www.thefreedictionary.com"]
    start_urls = listmaker()[:]
    print start_urls

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//*[@id="MainTxt"]/table/tbody')
        print 'SITES:\n',sites


        item = DicCrawlerItem()

        item["meanings"] = sites.select('//*[@id="MainTxt"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/text()').extract()

        print item

        return item
```

The listmaker() returns a list of urls to scrap.

My problem is that the *sites* variable comes up empty if I select till *'tbody'* in the xpath and returns an empty *sites* variable, Whereas if I select only table I get the part of the site I want.

I am not able to retrieve the meaning for a word as a result of this into item["meanings"] since the part after *tbody* is does not select beyond *tbody*.

Also while at it, the site gives multiple meanings which I would like to extract but I only know how to extract a single method.

Thanks

Comment: The HTML source code of your example page does not contain `tbody` elements, these were most probably added by your browser "inspect" tool. Also, you might want to loop on `<div class="pseg">`, and then for each -- "n.", "tr.v." etc -- you can loop on `<div class="ds-list">` to etract the different definition for each category

Comment: I've added an example spider as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a spider skeleton to get you started:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class Dic_crawler(BaseSpider):
    name = "thefreedictionary"
    allowed_domains = ["www.thefreedictionary.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shame']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        # loop on each "noun" or "verb" or something... section
        for category in hxs.select('id("MainTxt")//div[@class="pseg"]'):

            # this is simply to get what's in the <i> tag
            category_name = u''.join(category.select('./i/text()').extract())
            self.log("category: %s" % category_name)

            # for each category, a term can have multiple definition
            # category from .select() is a selector
            # so you can call .select() on it also,
            # here with a relative XPath expression selecting all definitions
            for definition in category.select('div[@class="ds-list"]'):
                definition_text = u'\n'.join(
                    definition.select('.//text()').extract())
                self.log(" - definition: %s" % definition_text)
```

Comment: Thanks works great. Would take me a little time to understand though.
If its not too much trouble could you tell me how the self.log works????

Comment: Quoting http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/topics/logging.html#logging-from-spiders, "The recommended way to log from spiders is by using the Spider log() method, which already populates the spider argument of the scrapy.log.msg()". Also see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/topics/debug.html#logging